# Token access to edit function of multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, token

I'm working on an application where a guest will be provided a short Base64 token that they could in turn use to access the edit function of one of several different models via one "search form" on the application homepage.

I have already created the token functionality and included it in the schema for the models I need.  My question is, how would one best search for and access the edit function using the access token from the home page?

I'm having a hard time finding a good way to do this and while I'm finding a lot about access tokens, most of it doesn't seem to pertain to my use case.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to accomplish. Can you provide some sample code that illustrates this?

Comment: Tough for me to illustrate with the level of code I've written for the task at this moment... Essentially what I'm hoping to accomplish is this: I have several models that have varying columns in their tables, most of which are different with the exception of `access_token`.  I'm hoping to find a method by which I can search all models by 'access_token` and open that record's edit path.  (example: @beds.access_token)

Comment: To better explain - is there an option to `Model.find(options)` that doesn't require the Model be known - just the options? (in this case, `something.find(access_token => % search input %)` for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails provides the ability for model classes to be inherited from a parent model class. Then the models can have shared attributes, but also unique ones. In the database all of these model objects are stored in the same table for all classes, so this is called Single Table Inheritance or STI. (Documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) but there are better docs in blog posts out there.)

If you use this approach, then you could search the parent class for all instances to find matching objects/records.

```
class AccessToken < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has attribute access_token, and maybe others
end

class OneAccessibleKind < AccessToken
  # may have other attributes
end

class AnotherAccessibleKind < AccessToken
  # may have other attributes
end
```

Your migration would look something like this:

```
create_table :access_token do |t|
  t.string "access_token"
  t.string "type"
  # add any additional attributes of subclasses

  t.timestamps
end
```

You can then query against the parent class. Note

```
all_models = AccessToken.where(access_token: 'a-token')
```

Note that these will all come back as `AccessToken` objects (i.e. the parent class), but you can inspect the `type` attribute to see what their base class is.

This may not be the best solution, however, if your classes are mostly different fields because you'll have lots of unused columns. Depending on your backing database (assuming row-oriented SQL) and number of objects this could be a performance problem.

Another option would be to use a one-to-one relationship and have an `AccessToken` model for each of your other models. Here you can use an STI association.

```
class AccessToken < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
end

class OneAccessibleKind < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :access_token, :as => :owner
end

class AnotherAccessibleKind < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :access_token, :as => :owner
end
```

With migrations something like this:

```
create_table :access_token do |t|
  t.string :access_token
  t.integer :owner_id, null: false
  t.string :owner_type, null: false

  t.timestamps
end

create_table :one_accessible_kind do |t|
  # any attributes for this type

  t.timestamps
end
```

Then you can find an access token and access each `owner` to get the objects.

```
AccessToken.where(access_token: 'a-token').map(&:owner)
```